# TortoiseGit and UnityYAMLMerge

Tags: unity-game-engine, version-control, diff, atlassian-sourcetree, tortoisegit

I'm trying to setup TortoiseGit to work with UnityYAMLMerge, but when I press to try to edit a .unity file conflict, I see a console window open up and close too fast to read anything in it.

I set it up just like in the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html) and this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RcJwamDAAGk

This is how I set it up:

[image]

What else can I do to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Smart Merge](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html)

> **UnityYAMLMerge** is shipped with a default **fallback file** (called **mergespecfile.txt**, also in the Tools folder) that specifies how it should proceed with unresolved conflicts or unknown files. This also allows you to use it as the main merge tool for version control systems (such as git) that don’t automatically select merge tools based on file extensions. The most common tools are already listed by default in mergespecfile.txt but **you can edit this file to add new tools or change options**.

---

## Using TortoiseGitMerge as fallback

Edit `C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\mergespecfile.txt` for **fallback file** and teach **UnityYAMLMerge** to use **TortoiseGitMerge**:

```
# TortoiseGitMerge
* use "%programs%\TortoiseGit\bin\TortoiseGitMerge.exe" /base:"%b" /mine:"%l" /theirs:"%r" /merged:"%d"
```

From [Resoving Unity Scene Merge Conflicts with UnityYAMLMerge (Smart Merge) and TortoiseGit](https://www.andreasjakl.com/resoving-unity-scene-merge-conflicts-unityyamlmerge-tortoisegit/)

[image]